# Missing title in Component Manager when enabling extension

Tags: magento2, extensions, component-manager

I have successfully developed a Magento2 extension (*yay!*) and managed to install it via composer (*double-yay!*). Now I'm trying to **enable** it.

I am doing this via the **Component Manager**, selecting "Enable" at my extension:
[image: Component manager]

In the next step some name or title of the extension seems to be missing - it just says **Enable *undefined***:
[image: Enable undefined]

Where is this title supposed to come from? Anyone who is able to track down the code location where this title is displayed?

(The process of enabling itself works fine. (Another *yay*.))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that this only happes when installing the extension from a cvs (like github). When installing from Packagist, it works!

[image]

Comment: What steps did you use to get the extension from GitHub?

Comment: Added my github repo to `\<mage-root>\composer.json` like here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository

Comment: I assume you're talking about two different extensions, one from packagist and one from GitHub. Maybe your GitHub `composer.json` is missing or has no namespace declaration `<vendor_name>/<package_name>`?

Comment: It's in fact the same extension, I submitted it to Packagist using my github repo. So the `composer.json` should be the same. But anyway I guess that the displayed name ("Ltc_Komfortkasse") comes from another file, `module.xml`.

Comment: That's correct. Thanks, I learned something!